# Installation problems with Ruby 2.4.1 on Mac OS/X only

Tags: travis-ci

I'm seeing persistent test failures, but only on Ruby 2.4.1, and only on Mac OS/X.  The code being tested works fine locally with Ruby 2.4.1 on Mac OS/X, and the problems appear to be an Ruby installation failure, not a build failure.

Is there a problem with travis-ci here?

https://travis-ci.org/rubys/nokogumbo/builds/238363298
https://travis-ci.org/rubys/nokogumbo/builds/238371578

The failure in question:

`Libraries missing for ruby-2.4.1: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib,/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an acknowledged travis bug: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7848